# Evaluating the integral $\int_C |\Bbb dz|/z$

Tags: mathematical-physics, complex-integration

I have to evaluate the integral $$\int_C \frac{|\Bbb dz|}{z}$$ where $C$ is the arc from $z = 1$ to $z = -1-i$.
So first of all I made the parameterization $z_1(1-t)+tz_2 = (1-t)x_1+tx_2+i((1-t)y_1+ty_2)$.
So I got $1-2t-it$. Then $\Bbb dz = -2\Bbb dt-i\Bbb dt \implies \Bbb dz = (-2-i)$ and $|\Bbb dz| = \sqrt 5 \Bbb dt$.
Then I put $$\int \frac{|\Bbb dz|}{z} = \int \frac{\sqrt 5\Bbb dt}{1-2t-it}.$$ And now I just need do integrate. But I’m not sure in previous steps.

Comment: Alex, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Comment: The above looks correct to me.

Comment: Just curious what do you mean by arc?